# How can implement two same objects with different behaviour?

Tags: c#, object, monogame

I am writing a c# monogame. I added two golmines, so the player can collect gold. I want that there is a limit for every mine. You can't collect more than 50 gold.
I implemented an object factory to get the mines:

```
case ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein:
    mActiveButtons.Add(ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString());
    if (GoldStock >= 0)
    {
        mButtons[ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString()].SetLocation(two);
        mButtons[ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString()].mAction = GoldVein.CollectGold;
        buttons[ObjectFactory.ObjectType.GoldVein.ToString()].UpdateText("Collect");
    }
    break;
```

GoldStock is my golmine limit. When there is no more GoldStock, than the player can't collect gold anymore.

Here is my CollectGold method:

```
public static void CollectGold(ObjectFactory.ObjectType type)
{
    Hud.mGold += 10;
    Hud.GoldStock -= 2;
}
```

mGold is the player gold supply.
What I want is, that every golmine has its own GoldStock. The player should get 50 gold in every mine. Now the mines are working together. There are 50 gold for the two mines in common.
How I can seperate it ?
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You have to keep separate instances of your gold mines, and don't share the gold through `static` variables.

A simple (console) example would be:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var goldMine1 = new GoldMine() { Gold = 50 };

        var goldMine2 = new GoldMine() { Gold = 50 };
    }
}

class GoldMine
{
    public int Gold { get; set; }
}
```

Each of these mines has its own stack of gold, which you can withdraw from separately.